# Loop over files and perform same operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
Example df
0   date          fruit
1   2010-01-01     apple
2   2010-01-01     pears
```

How do I loop over dataframes and then perform the same operations to each dataframe? I'm confused by the indentation and the order Python interprets the loop. Wanted generalisable code

```
lista = []
for x in [2010, 2017, 2020]:
    if x> 2015:
        for file in glob.glob(f'My Documents\Analysis\{x}\LateAnalysis\\*.csv'):
             df = pd.read_csv(file)
    else:
        for file in glob.glob(f'My Documents\Analysis\{x}\Early_Analysis\\*.csv'):
            df = pd.read_csv(file)
    #perform the same operations to each dataframe. Unsure about indendation of the below
    df = df.set_index('date')
    lista.append(df)
    ...
```

Comment: You need to put all the dataframes into a list and then loop over that list.

Comment: Or maybe you should put the processing inside the loop.

Comment: I tried that, updated the question to elaborate

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: `lista.append()` needs to be inside the `for` loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything that uses `df` needs to be inside the `for` loops. Otherwise you just get the last dataframe for each year.

You can also combine the `for` loops into a single loop by using a variable for the one difference between them.

```
lista = []
for x in [2010, 2017, 2020]:
    if x > 2015:
        filenames = rf'My Documents\Analysis\{x}\LateAnalysis\*.csv'
    else:
        filenames = rf'My Documents\Analysis\{x}\Early_Analysis\*.csv'
    for file in glob.glob(filenames):
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
        df = df.set_index('date')
        lista.append(df)
```

Comment: minor nit - I would specify the index column in the call to `read_csv`. I'd also add the `parse_dates` parameter (though if performance is an issue I might wait until all of the dataframes of concatenated outside the loop parse the dates and set the index)

Comment: Many thanks! If possible, would you mind explaining how Python interpreted my forloop attempt?

Comment: Each time through the loop it overwrites `df`. At the end of the loop it puts the last value into the list. So you just get the last file for each year, instead of all files for all years.

Comment: I'm getting the error: ```expected str, bytes, or PathLIke object, not list``` when I try to ```print(file)```

Comment: That's what you would get if you did `file = glob.glob(filenames)` instead of `for file in glob.glob(filenames):`

Comment: Wait a second. `print()` can print lists, it shouldn't get an error.

Comment: Please edit the question and show the full traceback.

Comment: Oh no sorry, i misread something in your code. I'm so sorry,

Comment: Would it be possible, sorry, to only perform the loop on files  that have the same name in all folders? I can update the question if easier

Comment: That should be a new question.

Comment: You can do it by making sets of filenames in each folder, then use the set intersection method to get all the names that are in all folders.

Comment: Then loop through the cross product of folder names and filenames.

Comment: Thanks. I listed it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66390583/loop-over-common-files-in-multiple-folders