# Loop over common files in multiple folders

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How could I find files with the same filename in multiple folders, and then perform the same operations?

```
def findCommonDeep(path1, path2):
    return set.intersection(*(set(os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, file), path) for root, _, files in os.walk(path) for file in files) for path in (path1, path2)))
```

```
lista = []
for x in [2010, 2017, 2020]:
    if x > 2015:
        filepath = rf'My Documents\Analysis\{x}\LateAnalysis\*.csv'
    else:
        filepath = rf'My Documents\Analysis\{x}\Early_Analysis\*.csv'

    fname = os.path.basename(filepath, filepath)
    findCommonDeep(fname)

    for file in glob.glob(filename_common):
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
        df = df.set_index('date')
        lista.append(df)
```

Comment: `findCommonDeep` is called using a single arg filename but is defined using 2 args about path.?

Comment: Yeah I was getting confused. Just need to find the common files between all folders

Comment: can you define what you mean by common file?

Comment: For example ```"file1.csv"``` in all folders

Comment: Just glob them all recursively: glob.glob('**/file1.csv')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've tagged pandas, let's use `pandas` and `pathlib` to return a dictionary of files with similar names:

```
from pathlib import Path 
import pandas as pd 

def return_similair_files(start_dir : str) -> dict:

   all_files = Path(start_dir).rglob('*.csv')
   df = pd.DataFrame({'files' : all_files})
   df['name'] = df['files'].apply(lambda x : x.name) #pathlib method. 

   return df.groupby('name')['files'].agg(list).to_dict()
```

---

This will return a dictionary of files, like so:

```
{'file_1.csv' : [list_of_paths]}
```

You can then operate on them as you need.

Comment: Thanks! Do I run the function in the loop or? Whereabouts exactly?

Comment: @asd no the function replaces the loop, you can then create dataframes quite simply, by calling `dfs = {name : pd.read_csv(f) for name, file in dictionary.items() for f in files}` or something like that :)

Comment: Thanks. If the function has one parameter, ```start_dir```, where do the other folders filepaths go? Sorry for misunderstanding. If ```start_dir``` represents: ```'My Documents\Analysis\```, I guess that can't work since that folder has other unrelated CSVs

Comment: @asd sorry missed this comment, you're misunderstanding `rglob` it trawls an entire directory structure. you can filter it by using the many `pathlib` methods to filter your paths. You'll have to update your question with a more specific usecase as I don't understand from your question

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. How do I practically use the function. After running your function, do I run ```return_similair_files('My Documents\Analysis\')```? Where would I filter the paths?

Comment: Check out [`pandas-path`](https://github.com/drivendataorg/pandas-path/), which adds an accesor `.path`, and makes it easy to replace the `lambda` in line `df['name'] = df['files'].apply(lambda x : x.name)`  with just `df.files.path.name`.